Coil Image URI Painter Issue
private fun Header(
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = modifier,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            /**
             * Displaying product images if available
             */
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
            if (images.isNotEmpty()) {
                val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0) {images.size}

                HorizontalPager(
                    state = pagerState,
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                ) { page ->
                    Image(
                        painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(model = images[page]),
                        contentDescription = "Picture of the product",
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                    )
                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp))
                HorizontalPagerIndicator(
                    pagerState = pagerState,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                        .padding(16.dp)
                )
            } else {
                /**
                 * Show placeholder image if no images are available
                 */
                val placeholder: Painter = painterResource(id = type.placeholderResID)
                Image(
                    painter = placeholder,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .aspectRatio(16 / 9f)
                        .padding(8.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }

    }

I have internet permission in AndroidManifest, image uris are valid
enter image description here
When i debug it seems that it doesnt go inside page ->
After searching on the internet

I updated coil version,
tried giving different permissions (external storage but i fetch the images on the internet so it was useless)
added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"  to the manifest file
someone said uri parser might not parse correctly  So if you encode and decode your URI at some point, make sure to convert the final ":" character to "%3A", otherwise it fails.

givenImages.add(Uri.parse(child.entryValueString))  Mine works like this, i tried to change it up but didnt know what to do, as seen in the picture image urls are already extracted correctly
Nothing worked

show image with coil :
 val painter = imageUrl.asyncImagePainter()
                    Image(
                    painter = painter,
                    contentDescription = "",
                    contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                )

